# Issues when converting mysql_* into mysqli_*. The code doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code that I got from the internet for "Check Username availability".

It is written with `mysql_*` but I want to convert it into `mysqli_*` , because `mysql_*` will be no more supported in PHP7.

But after converting it doesn't work, the username it is not checked and I always become the **Green Tick**.

I tried the OOP programming also Procedural , and in the end I just added in the end of mysql an "i" for mysqli. This is the code with mysql_*. Can anyone help with converting?

File **dbConnector.php** :

```
 <?php

 class DbConnector {

var $theQuery;
var $link;

function DbConnector(){

    // Get the main settings from the array we just loaded
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db = 'accesspi';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';

    // Connect to the database
    $this->link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    mysql_select_db($db);
    register_shutdown_function(array(&$this, 'close'));

   }

  //*** Function: query, Purpose: Execute a database query ***
function query($query) {

    $this->theQuery = $query;
    return mysql_query($query, $this->link);

 }

   //*** Function: fetchArray, Purpose: Get array of query results ***
function fetchArray($result) {

    return mysql_fetch_array($result);

  }
  //*** Function: close, Purpose: Close the connection ***
  function close() {

     mysql_close($this->link);
 }
}
?>
```

File **check.php**

```
<?php
include("dbConnector.php");
$connector = new DbConnector();

$username = trim(strtolower($_POST['username']));
$username = mysql_escape_string($username);

$query = "SELECT username FROM admin WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1";
$result = $connector->query($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo $num;
mysql_close();
?>
```

File **index.php**  with javascript code

```
<link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript"    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#username').keyup(username_check);
});

function username_check(){  
var username = $('#username').val();
if(username == "" || username.length < 4){
$('#username').css('border', '3px #CCC solid');
$('#tick').hide();
}else{

jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "check.php",
data: 'username='+ username,
cache: false,
success: function(response){
if(response == 1){
$('#username').css('border', '3px #C33 solid'); 
$('#tick').hide();
$('#cross').fadeIn();
}else{
$('#username').css('border', '3px #090 solid');
$('#cross').hide();
$('#tick').fadeIn();
     }

  }
  });
  }
   }

</script>

<style>
#username{
padding:3px;
font-size:18px;
border:3px #CCC solid;
}

#tick{display:none}
#cross{display:none}


</style>
</head>

 <body>


 Username: <input name="username" id="username" type="text" />
<img id="tick" src="tick.png" width="16" height="16"/>
<img id="cross" src="cross.png" width="16" height="16"/>

</body>
</html>
```

The converted files dbConnector. php

```
 <?php

 class DbConnector {

 var $result;
 var $conn;

 function DbConnector(){

    // Get the main settings from the array we just loaded
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db = 'accesspi';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';

    // Connect to the database
    $conn= mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

  }

 //*** Function: query, Purpose: Execute a database query ***
 function query($query) {

        $result = $conn->query($query);

  }

  //*** Function: fetchArray, Purpose: Get array of query results ***
  function fetchArray($result) {

    return $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

  }

  //*** Function: close, Purpose: Close the connection ***
  function close() {

  $conn->close();

}

 }

 ?>
```

and check.php

```
     <?php
   include("dbConnector.php");
   $connector = new DbConnector();
   if (isset($_POST['username'])){
   $username = trim(strtolower($_POST['username']));
   $username = $connector->real_escape_string($username);

    $query = "SELECT username FROM admin WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1";
   $result = $connector->query($query);
   $num = $result->num_rows;

  echo $num;
  $connector->close();
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: SO is *not* a code conversion service.

Comment: You show us the convertion you did and we will point out any errors. **We dont write it for you**

Comment: I will post the convertion right now

Comment: I posted it can you see it RiggsFolly

Comment: Now give us a little clue what is not working with the converted code

Comment: The first thing you need to reasearch is the use of `$this` in a class

Comment: And unless you are using PHP4 you dont need `var` to define class properties but you might lookup `public` and `protected` and `private` keywords and where they relate to class property and method definition

Comment: I have solved all code errors of these two files and I don't get any error anymore but the username check doesn't work, I become only green tick , I can't find why

Comment: I am afraid you have not solved them all

Comment: But when I execute these two files I don't get any error

Comment: Thats because you are not looking for any. Add these 2 lines to the top of `check.php` - `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Then look at `function query($query) {....` and see what you forgot to do with the `$result`

Comment: The code is solved ! It works now

Comment: But do you see the difference and understand what was wrong with your original try? In other words did you learn anything other than copy/paste?

Comment: I am trying to understand it now because are some things that I don't understand

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
class DbConnector {

    private $theQuery;
    private $link;

    public function __construct(){

        // Get the main settings from the array we just loaded
        $host = 'localhost';
        $db = 'accesspi';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = '';

        // Connect to the database
        $this->link = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass,$db);
        register_shutdown_function(array(&$this, 'close'));
    }

    /**
     * Function: query, Purpose: Execute a database query
     * @param $query
     * @return bool|mysqli_result
     */
    public function query($query) {

        $this->theQuery = $query;
        return $this->link->query($query);

    }

    /**
     * Function: fetchArray, Purpose: Get array of query results
     * @param $result mysqli_result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function fetchArray($result) {
        return $result->fetch_array();
    }

    /**
     * Function: close, Purpose: Close the connection
     */
    public function close() {
        if(isset($this->link)){
            $this->link->close();
            unset($this->link);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return mysqli
     */
    public function getLink(){
        return $this->link;
    }


}
```

check.php:

```
<?php
include("dbConnector.php");
$connector = new DbConnector();

$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'username',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$username = $connector->getLink()->real_escape_string($username);

$query = "SELECT username FROM admin WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1";
$result = $connector->query($query);
$num = $result->num_rows;

echo $num;
$connector->close();
```

Comment: No it doesn't work , i am still getting always a green tick

Comment: It has a problem in this line  public function close() {
        $this->link->close();
    }

Comment: what problem? For me it works fine.. maybe wrap it with if($this->link) $this->link->close();

Comment: Now it comes syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Comment: can you please copy the class again from the answer and try again

Comment: I did it and I get this     0
Warning: mysqli::close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\username\check-username\dbConnector.php on line 46

Comment: try to add `unset($this->link)` after `$this->link->close();`. Because you shutdown function will try to close the connection again but it is already closed but the if return still true

Comment: Now I get  Notice: Undefined property: DbConnector::$link in C:\xampp\htdocs\username\check-username\dbConnector.php on line 46

Fatal error: Call to a member function close() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\username\check-username\dbConnector.php on line 46

Comment: copy close method again from anwer

Comment: YES it Worked :D Thank you very muchhh

Comment: I have a question. Can you explain me this $this because I do not understand these parts : $this->theQuery = $query; and this return $this->link->query($query);

Comment: And why did you change the function DbConnector () into public function_construct()

Comment: `$this->theQuery = $query; ` is only needed if you want to add some kind of "lastQueryMethod" later, otherwise you could also leave that out.. $this meanse the instance of dbConnector - so we can access the methods and properties of this class i.e. link ($this->link).. link is instance of mysqli to we can access methods of mysqli ($this->link->query($query)).. at least query() will return a mysqli_result instance which we forward with our return

Comment: [And why did you change the function DbConnector () into public function_construct() ]: It's just my way of doing it.. if you now want to rename the class you do not need it to do in two places.. I also like directly to see if the method is private, protected or public

Comment: But this variable $query that becoms this value $this->theQuery = $query;  is than here inserted  $this->link->query($query);. The two variables that are defined on the top I don't understand very well

Comment: Instead of using this $this->link = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass,$db); why doesn't work when it's done like this $conn=new mysqli($host, $user, $pass,$db); and than using this $conn everywhere